# How do I make the red button quit app

Tags: mac

I have just got a mac and I cannot get over the fact that the red button doesn't quit the app and it is still running in the background. Is there any way round this???? I do know how to quit the app, I just want it to do it when I do the button. Anything helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MacOS!!   I believe the answer is no...  I'd suggest simply getting used to using Command-Q when you want to close an app.  Don't even need to close the window if you don't want.    It's a bit of a learning curve when you're used to Windows but you get used to it quickly enough.

Comment: Some apps do quit when their last window closes (especially if they have only one window, e.g. System Preferences). And even when they don't quit, they tend to use minimal resources, so it may not be worth worrying too much about. But no, I don't think there's any way to change that behaviour, I'm afraid.

Comment: I remember having similar feelings when I switched to Mac. Believe it or not, today I find it annoying that Windows terminate the program while I just wanted to close the window. Window just closes the window if the app has another one open, but terminates the app if it’s the last one. It’s actually more consistent on the Mac where the user always has the choice.

Comment: It is up to the programmer to decide what the button does. In most of my apps I select the option to close, but many do not. Some allow the user to select in preferences. I find it annoying when apps do not close.

Comment: On Windows, each window of an app is its own instance. On Mac the application can contain many windows, all under the same instance. It's a completely different way of doing things. Learn to Cmd/Q.

Comment: So Cmnd + Tab will bring up a "list" of running Apps, and with Cmnd still pressed just get to the one(s) you want to quit and hit q.

Comment: @Milliways The programmer should follow the Human Interface Guidelines. Arbitrarily changing expected and consistent OS behaviours is as annoying as it gets.

Comment: I built a small application that quits apps when the last window is closed "Red X Button".  You can find it at [SwiftQuit.com](https://swiftquit.com). Maybe that will help you out.

Comment: @Charlie74 Why? We should have fully control of our computer

Answer (score 0):

Document-based applications in MacOS are designed to stay active even when they have no documents open. (However, apps with only one window, e.g. System Preferences, will quit when their window is closed.)

This is different from other OSes, and trying to 'make it' behave differently from its design is fruitless.

MacOS manages the RAM usage of applications very efficiently, so you don't need to worry about apps running and it's much faster to have the app 'there' and ready when you next want to open a document.

Comment: The thing is that I want to decide myself which apps should stay open, and having two buttons doing the same (red and yellow) is redundant... Because when I always just click the red button and I want to close these apps by doing so, somewhen there will be a mess and 10 apps will be open at some point.

Comment: @watchme Red and Yellow buttons don't do the same thing. Red closes the window; yellow hides it in the Dock. Neither of them quits the app. Windows and apps are different things.